# How to prove that if $a$ belongs to $\mathbb R$, such that $0\leq a \leq\epsilon$, then $a = 0$

Tags: real-analysis

I am taking a real analysis course. I have the following statement:

> Prove that if  $a$ belongs to $\mathbb R$,  such that  $0\leq a <  \epsilon$, for all $\epsilon > 0$, then $a = 0$

I know how to prove it (using contradiction). Now, I was wondering, how I prove almost the same thing:

> Prove that if  $a$ belongs to $\mathbb R$,  such that  $0\leq a \leq \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, then $a = 0$

Can someone show me how to do it? I am stuck with the equality to show a contradiction.

Note: this is not homework, just for my own knowledge.

Comment: What is `e`? Do you mean that $a$ is a real number such that for every $\epsilon > 0$, $0 \le a \le \epsilon$? Quantifiers ("for all", "there exists"...) are important, you can't leave them out.

Comment: Is it just me or your second question is *exactly* like the first one? And what is there to prove? What number other than $a = 0$ is smaller than *every* positive number out there?

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). You can [edit] your question to improve formatting and content (the content in particular needs work, as others said).

Comment: It does seem you that you would just have: $0\leq a\leq \epsilon\rightarrow 0\leq a<\epsilon\rightarrow a=0$ where you already proved that $0\leq a<\epsilon\rightarrow a=0$ and showing $0\leq a\leq \epsilon\rightarrow 0\leq a<\epsilon$ is trivial

Comment: My guess is that you proved that
$$\forall a\in \mathbb R\left(\forall \varepsilon\in ]0,\infty[\left(0\leq a<\varepsilon\right)\implies a=0\right)$$
and you want to prove that
$$\forall a\in \mathbb R\left(\forall \delta\in ]0,\infty[\left(0\leq a\leq \delta\right)\implies a=0\right).$$ So take an arbitrary $a\in \mathbb R$ and assume that $\forall \delta\in ]0,\infty[\left(0\leq a\leq \delta\right)$. By virtue of what you previously proved, it's enough to prove that $\forall \varepsilon\in ]0,\infty[\left(0\leq a<\varepsilon\right)$ holds. Do it.

Comment: Sorry, e > 0. @user159813 yes, but I want to prove 0 <= a <= e Git Gud, you are saying d > 0, right? I don't understand why "it is enough to prove that..." holds. Can you elaborate a bit for me?

Comment: @Edwardo If you prove that $\varepsilon\in ]0,\infty[\left(0\leq a<\varepsilon\right)$, then, because of what you proved, it follows $a=0$.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi e > 0, Sorry I edited it

Comment: $\varepsilon \downarrow 0$, implies $a=0$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If $a>0$ then $0\leq a\leq \epsilon$ is not true for $\epsilon=\frac{a}{2}>0$

If $a<0$ then it is immediate that $0\leq a\leq \epsilon$ is not true.

So the only 'candidate' that remains is $a=0$ and it is obvious that the statement is true for $a=0$

Comment: Man that is a way more concise and simple way to prove this than what I just wrote.

Comment: Is the same proof for what I prove! you are right!

Answer (score 1):

If this is the situation Najid Idrissi described it as this another way to prove it.

Assume $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that for $\epsilon>0$ that $0\leq a\leq\epsilon$ (i.e. $a\in[0,\epsilon]$). Well this means that $a\in[0,\frac{1,}{n}]$ for $n>0$. This then indicates that 
$$a\in\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[0,\frac{1}{n}\right]$$
Well we note that 
$$0\in\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[0,\frac{1}{n}\right]$$
Thus all we must prove is that there is no other element within intersection. Seeking a contradiction suppose that there is a $c\neq0$ such that  $c\in\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[0,\frac{1}{n}\right]$. Well since $c\neq0$ then $c>0$ but this means that $c\not\in[0,\frac{c}{2}]$ but this means that for $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $m>\frac{2}{c}$ then for all such $m$ $c\not\in[0,\frac{1}{m}]\subset[0,\frac{c}{2}]$ which is a contradiction thus 
$$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[0,\frac{1}{n}\right]=\{0\}$$
and since $a\in\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[0,\frac{1}{n}\right]$, we have that $a\in\{0\}$ thus $a=0$