# How to prove for every $ε > 0$, it holds that $0 \le a < ε$, then $a = 0$

Tags: real-analysis

I have a difficulty on proving this statement;

> For every $a$ in $R$ the following holds:
>
> If for every $ε > 0$ it holds that $0 \le a < ε$, then $a = 0$.

I have tried to prove the statement with the **trichotomy** and the technique of proving by contradiction as follows;

> Assume that $0 \le a < ε$, then there are 3 possiblities for $a$ and $0$ based on Trichotomy; $a = 0$, $a < 0$ or $a >0$
>
> $a<0$ does not hold based on the assumption.  So, either $a = 0$ or $a >0$.
>
> If we multiply $a >0$ by $ε$ on both side;
>
> $$a  ε >  0   ε$$
> $$aε > 0$$

Now I have $aε > 0$, and  I have no clue to prove that $a = 0$.

Comment: This question has been asked several times recently.

Comment: @Did: Sorry, I didn't see this before answering ...

Comment: @Did: If so, I would like to have the link to the questions because I could not find anything like this. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prove that if $a$ belongs to $\mathbb R$, such that $0\leq a \leq\epsilon$, then $a = 0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/907183/how-to-prove-that-if-a-belongs-to-mathbb-r-such-that-0-leq-a-leq-epsilon)

Comment: @CristhianGz: Thanks

Comment: $\varepsilon \downarrow 0$, implies $a=0$

Comment: @CristhianGz: Not a duplicate. The question you link assume that the answer to _this_ one is already known, an instead asks about how to prove that the weaker assumption $a\le \epsilon$ works instead of $a<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have for **all** $\epsilon > 0$  that $0 \leq a < \epsilon$. With $a$ being fixed assume that $a > 0$ (that is assume that $a\neq 0$). What happens when $\epsilon = \frac{a}{2}$?

Comment: it contradicts the assumption that $ε > a$.

Comment: @FarahFai: Exactly, so the assumption that $a>0$ must be wrong, and $a$ must be $0$.

Comment: But when $a = 0$ and $ε = \frac{a}{2}$, the $ε$ will be $0$...

Comment: Except you have assumed $a>0$.

Here is the full proof in detail, hopefully it dispels any remaining problems.

Suppose for every $\varepsilon>0$ we that $0 \leq a < \varepsilon$. We shall assume $a \neq 0$ and reach a contradiction. From our assumption it now follows that $a/2 > 0$, so $a < a/2$. Clearly we have a contradiction, hence $a=0$.

Comment: @Pelto: You just rewrote my proof... Note that assuming that $a>0$ is the same as assuming that $a\neq0$. My proof is a proof by contradiction.

Comment: Clearly. I was just trying to put things in different words since FarahFai was still seeming to not fully understand. Really hope you are not getting upset about me trying to steal your result or something. This is a pretty unoriginal and trivial argument. If I wanted to steal reputation then I would have posted my comment as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Do you know how to use the @ symbol when writing comments? If you comment on an answer without using the @ symbol, then the answerer will assume that the comment is meant for him/her.

Comment: I thought it was pretty obvious from context and the fact that FarahFai posted right before me.