# A question similar to theorem 2.9.1 in Bartle & Sherbert "Introduction to Real Analysis "

Tags: real-analysis

prove that if $a\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $0 \leq a \leq \epsilon,$ for every $\epsilon > 0,$ then $a=0.$

What is the difference between proving this and the following theorem in Bartle, [*Introduction to Real Analysis* (2011 4 ed)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471433314),  p 28?

[image]

Comment: No difference, the same proof works. In theory, you could have chosen $\epsilon=a$ for the proof of **2.1.9**.

Comment: It may seem to be a trivial result but it actually comes up in analysis a lot, when we find a sequence of approximations converging to some value, and show that the approximations  are non-negative and can be as close to 0 as we like.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove that if $a$ belongs to $\mathbb R$, such that $0\leq a \leq\epsilon$, then $a = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/907183/how-to-prove-that-if-a-belongs-to-mathbb-r-such-that-0-leq-a-leq-epsilon)